# How to include page layout for a custom html page in Octopress

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, markdown, blogs, octopress

I have an octopress blog, I want to serve a custom html file but, meanwhile I want it to have a built-in layout.

For example if I do `rake new_page['about']`, and I can have a new about page and I can edit `about/index.markdown` and specify the layout.

Instead of markdown I want `about/index.html`, but when I do that I can't specify the layout like

`File: about/index.html`

`{% include head.html %}`

How can I create a custom html page and specify a built in layout just as I can do for a custom markdown page.

Answer (score 0):

What did you exactly call a **layout** ?

You already have a variable `layout: page` in your front matter. Just change this variable for you new custom layout name.

Comment: It works for markdown, but doesn't work for index.html